# How to replace string between two stated chars in javascript

Tags: javascript, replace, replaceall

I want to replace some codes to dom elements. For example:

```
[emo]sad[emo] or [emo]sad[/emo]
```

to

```
<span class='smiley medium' data-emo='" + emo + "'></span>
```

like

```
<span class='smiley medium' data-emo='sad'></span>
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Where do these "codes" live?

Comment: inside a <li> appended a <ul> element. i get li's innerhtml from server with ajax

Comment: is 'emo' in data-emo supposed to be a variable containing the content of [emo] tag?

Comment: yes, for example [happy] will be sent to server and get back [emo]happy[emo] to client. so i want to convert it a smiley by a span tag

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
var s1 = "[emo]sad[emo]";
var s2 = "[emo]sad[/emo]";

var regex = /^\[(\w+)\](.+)\[\/?(\w+)\]$/; // matches s1 and s2
var replacement = "<span class='smiley medium' data-$1='$2'></span>";
var s1HTML = s1.replace(regex,replacement);
var s2HTML = s2.replace(regex,replacement);

// now append s1HTML and s2HTML to dom
```

Breaking down the reg ex:

```
var regex = /
  ^            // start
  \[(\w+)\]    // the first [] block, match inside the []
  (.+)         // match between the [] blocks
  \[\/?(\w+)\] // the second [] block, optional "/", match inside the []
  $            // end
/;
```

jsbin: https://jsbin.com/nofizosebe/1/edit?js,console

Comment: This is right. However, in this particular case, you can replace `\[(\w+)\]` with `\[emo\]` and `\[\/?(\w+)\]` with `\[\/?emo\]`

Comment: Thank you for answer Jonathan and Stefano. What about "[emo]sad[emo] [emo]happy[emo]" ? Should this return me 2span tags? If so I am doing something wrong

Comment: @PcodeaXonos If you have a string like that I would recommend splitting it up into 2 separate strings and then running it through the regex.

Comment: I dont know how many [emo] will be, Its dynamic. I think I need a foreach loop?

Comment: @PcodeaXonos right, `split` it into an array and then use a `forEach` loop